# Icons missing and misbehaving in Gnome Panel since 15.04 upgrade

Tags: gnome, indicator, gnome-panel

This is the top right corner of my screen, where my Gnome Panel displays notification icons. I am using Flashback or Fallback or Classic or whatever it's called right now.

[image: Gnome panel icons]

It is missing the Dropbox and sound icons. Also, although I switch between Japanese (Anthy) and US English input, the "En" icon does not change. These problems emerged after upgrading to 15.04.

I have tried running `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`, I have tried deleting all indicator areas and reinstalling them. Nothing has changed.

How do I get Dropbox and sound icons back in my Gnome Panel?

Comment: Concerning input layout indicator, how do you switch layout? which input method are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following two solutions:

For sound, running this at the command line restored my sound icon:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
```

For Dropbox and for my IME input indicator, it seems that removing everything from the Gnome panel, and then adding "indicator app complete" and "notification area", and then restarting helped. However, my Dropbox icon and IME icons both look jacked up:

[image: indicator apps]

Oh well, at least they're back now. Note the icon that says "En" never changes, even though the one that says "US" will change to show what input method I am currently using.

Comment: your suggestion makes my Dropbox indicators show up again. I just need to add "Notification area" then restart Dropbox deamon. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit dropbox.desktop file and change Exec line to:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start -i
```

For me one dropbox.desktop is in ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop, but it probably depends on how you installed dropbox. I would suggest to search for all dropbox.desktop files and change Exec line in all files.

If you don't want to edit files you can add Notification Area applet to panel:

```
Alt + Right click -> Add to Panel...
```

**Edit:**
Autostart file for some reason is reverted. After short testing it looks like you also need to edit /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop file.

1. Stop dropbox:

   dropbox stop
2. Change Exec line in /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop file:

   sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
3. Change Exec line in ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop file:

   gedit ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop